# Choose not to save an element on EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events

I want to do some server side checks to see if the entry should be saved or not.

In my plugin I have something like that

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent $event) {
        if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Entry) {
            $entry = $event->element;
            if ( $entry->sectionId == 5 ) {
                $entry->enabled = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

This works but what I want is for the entry to not be saved rather then be disabled. Something I could achive on the user model with:

```
$event->isValid = false;
```

Is there a way to withhold the entry from saving? The only other solution I can think if is to make the tests in the AFTER event and delete it if not passing the condition.

Comment: Just a heads up in case no solution is found: Deleting an element after it's saved would seriously screw up your database's indexes (auto-increment columns mostly),  though you wouldn't really notice it since craft would be managing all things SQL-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality or behavior is a bit confusing. The Elements Service [has its own Events](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/services/Elements.php#L1877-L1882) for saving *Elements*, specifically... but because ultimately Elements are just Yii Models, [they have a discrete `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` event](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/base/Element.php#L2218-L2224) that uses a ModelEvent, which [has the `isValid` property](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-modelevent#$isValid-detail).

This is the point in the life-cycle where saving the Element can be prevented. The `beforeSave` method is called on the Element being saved (usually overridden in the actual Element implementation, but [called + returned at the end of the subclass's method](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/elements/Entry.php#L1217), like `parent::beforeSave($isNew)`), and the resulting boolean (`$event->isValid`) [determines whether or not the saving continues](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/services/Elements.php#L1884-L1886).

So, in short: You can listen directly to the Entry's `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` event to prevent it from saving:

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\ModelEvent;

use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
            $entry = $event->sender;
            if ($entry->sectionId == 5) {
                $event->isValid = false;
            }
        }
    });
```